# Incrementing a variable in a cycle (modulo)

Tags: javascript, increment

I wish to cycle the values of a variable (call it `x`) through the pattern 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, … upon activation of a function (call it `update`). I've managed to get 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, … by doing:

```
var x = 0;

function update() {
  x = ++x % 3;
}
```

Then I tried the post-increment operator instead, and the value of `x` just remains at 0:

```
var x = 0;

function update() {
  x = x++ % 3;
}
```

Then the more I thought about this code, the more confused I got. I think 0 modulo 3 is being done first, then the assignment (of 0) to `x`, but then is `x` not incremented to 1? (it seems that it isn't, but that's not what I want anyway — I want the pattern to start at 0. Can someone explain what's going on with this code and how to achieve the pattern starting at 0?

Comment: What about doing simply `x = (x+1) % 3;` ? I think writing `x = x++` is really weird... because logically, `x++` would be executed, it would return the previous value of `x` and assign it to `x`, its initial value, so to me, `x = x++ % 3` should be the same as `x = x % 3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second example of code is doing this

1. Store the old value of x
2. Increment x
3. Modulo the old value of x by 3
4. Store the result of the modulus in x

Your first code should give you the correct solution if you call it like this:

```
look_at_value()
update()
look_at_value()
update()
...
```

If you want to call update before looking at the value, you will need to initialize `x = -1` (or 2 mod 3)

Clearer code would be:

```
function update() {
    x = (x+1) % 3;
}
```